# Увеличение переменной внутри цикла

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать, чтобы при каждой итерации j значение переменной k увеличивалось на 5? То бишь когда j=2, то k=5, а когда j=3, то k=10 и так далее.

```
        for (var j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
            if (number == j) {
                var k = 5;
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (i < k || i >= k + 5) {
                        console.log(123);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `k = (j -1)*5 `

Comment: Как я понял k = (j - 1) * 5 ?

Comment: Спасибо, братцы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то вот:

```js
for (var j = 2, k = 5; j < 5; j++, k = k + 5) {
            if (true) {
              console.log(k);
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (i < k || i >= k + 5) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `if (true) {` - гениально. Проще не писать.

Comment: @And Да, проще, но ведь это же просто для теста, переменной number ведь не было в примере, а внутри был console.log(123), на автомате поставил замену, чтобы увидеть результат всех итераций и убедиться что все работает как ожидается внутри остальных конструкций. В конце стер лишний лог, чтобы не мешал выводу искомого результата. Не знаю зачем объясняю, но по-видимому иначе вы не поймете.

Comment: @And по поводу переменной, а зачем мне её вообще определять, если нужно определить только условие?)